# How to do looping in perl for makefile

Tags: linux, perl, makefile

I am trying to automate the creation of php class with `makefile` and `perl` `oneliner`.

I have this file `document.txt`

```
[ENTITY]
Document
MyDefaultBundle
number:string(200)
issueDate:datetime
expiryDate:datetime
file_path:string(200)
filename:string(200)
description:text
document_type:string(200)
```

Basically firstline is `classname` , second is `Bundlename` and third is `fields`

I am using this in make file to execute symfony command to generate classes

```
MYFILE = Entity/document.txt
READ_ENTITY=eval `perl -l -00pe 'y/\n\r[]/ /d; s/([A-Z]+) (\w+) (\w+) (.*)/$$1=$$3:$$2\nFIELDS="$$4"\n/g' $1`
mytest:
        $(call READ_ENTITY,$(MYFILE)) && $(SYMFONY_COMMAND) --entity=$$ENTITY --fields="$$FIELDS"
```

This is working fine for one entity. (i have escaped $ with $$)

Now my condition is that i have multiple ENTITIES in loop

`document.txt`

```
[ENTITY]
Document
MyDefaultBundle
number:string(200)
issueDate:datetime
expiryDate:datetime
file_path:string(200)
filename:string(200)
description:text
document_type:string(200)

[ENTITY]
Document2
MyDefaultBundle
number:string(200)
issueDate:datetime
expiryDate:datetime
file_path:string(200)
filename:string(200)
description:text
document_type:string(200)

[ENTITY]
Document3
MyDefaultBundle
number:string(200)
issueDate:datetime
expiryDate:datetime
file_path:string(200)
filename:string(200)
description:text
document_type:string(200)
```

so i want to execute that statement in loop. I am not sure how to do that inside make file.

basically with `eval` i ama making shell variable `ENTITY` AND `FIELDS` and then using that in symfony command line

Any ideas??

EDIT:

For the perl command the document.txt shown above, that is input

The output of perl coomand is

```
ENTITY=MyDefaultBundle:Document
FIELDS="number:string(200) issueDate:datetime expiryDate:datetime file_path:string(200) filename:string(200) description:text document_type:string(200)"
```

which basically makes them as shell variable so that i can insert them with `$ENTITY`

The problem is when i have multiple [ENTITY] seprated by space then i can't use that as last entry with overwrite the ENTITY VARIABLE.

i want some thing like

```
for [ENTITY] IN document.txt
   EXECUTE $(call READ_ENTITY,$(MYFILE)) && $(SYMFONY_COMMAND) --entity=$$ENTITY --fields="$$FIELDS"
```

So that in each loop i have different `ENTITY` and `FIELDS` variable

Comment: Not clear what the inputs and outputs are. If you could demonstrate an example input, the command that generates the output and the output, that would help.

Comment: The Perl command modifies `Entity/document.txt` in place, then the symfony command scans it and produces... another file, is that correct?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin i have added more details

Comment: @Beta no perl commands dont modify any file. symfony command only needs $ENTITY AND $FEILDS VARIABLE thats it

Comment: All right, and what does the symfony command produce?

Comment: @Beta then symfony creates new file php automatically. its symfony build in commans , it just needs name and fields then it make php files automatically. i just want to do that so that i can define the config in text file rather than writing on command line

Comment: *What is the name of the new php file?*

Comment: @Beta that will be `Document.php` which is the first variable after [ENTITY]

Answer (score 0):

You may not need a loop here if you put makefile pattern rules to use.

1. Create one input file for each output php document.
2. Create a pattern rule that takes one input file and produces one php document. Make sure the command produces the file that is the target name:

   ```
   # Take input files from Entity/, produce outputs in Documents/
   Documents/Document%.php : Entity/document%.txt
       EXECUTE $(call READ_ENTITY,$<) && $(SYMFONY_COMMAND) --entity=$$ENTITY --fields="$$FIELDS" --output-filename=$@
   ```
3. Create a rule that depends on the documents that need to be built:

   ```
   all : Documents/Document1.php Documents/Document2.php Documents/Document3.php
   .PHONY: all
   ```
4. Invoke `make all`. If target `all` is the first target in your makefile (it is a convention), then just `make`.

Comment: First of all i have only one `document.txt` which have data to make many PHP files. i don't need to give any output filename as syfony will generate it from the config inside `document.txt`. so input is always `document.txt` and output will be php file generated by symfony. so one execute will give one file. [ENTITY] contains all the config for one php file. For one [ENTITY] config , i can create one Entity ok. But i want to have multiple `[ENTITY]` tags in `document.txt` so that for every separate [ENTITY] tag i get seprate file whose output filename will be from first line after [ENTITY] tag